# Quicksort non recursive

Tags: python, quicksort, non-recursive

The statement says:

Write a nonrecursive (negative) function which given a list of integers (possibly disordered) function returns the same list with negative numbers to positive head and back (regardless of the order between them). This algorithm can be solved in the form requested a similar strategy (though a bit more simple) partition in quicksort.

I put this code:

```
def negatius(a):

    fin = len(a) - 1
    i = 0
    b = [i]

    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] < 0:
            b[fin] = a[i]
            i += 1

        else:
            b[fin] = a[i]
            fin += 1

    print "La llista és",b[fin]


a=[1,-2,3,-4,-3,5,6]
negatius(a)
```

And appears an error: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment. I dont understand this

Comment: Don't use `int` as a variable name, you hide the built in `int`

Comment: Ok but my int += 1 is removed

Comment: I would suggest going through [Google's Python Class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) or a similar tutorial to better understand Python basics. Also, please don't change your code while your question is being answered. Your current code includes the fix for the error you asked about, so now the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Could you give some examples of possible inputs and the correct outputs? It's not entirely clear to me what the code should do.

Comment: @skrrgwasme, of course it is ok to alter code.

Comment: @Christian: what is a negative function?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Perhaps I phrased it too strongly. Yes editing code is sometimes appropriate, but not in a way that completely invalidates the question. The OP is asking about an undefined variable error. The new version of the code throws an entirely different error.

Comment: I'd say it is rather ok to do that than create several question for this trivial thing.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I suppose that's where we disagree. Your answer below is a perfect example of why [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) should be discouraged. Your answer below is a good example of fixing the OPs broken code, but if some future visitor opens this question because they googled "local variable referenced before assignment", your answer does nothing for them. Each SO question should have a well-defined focus. Opening new questions when the focus shifts helps keep everything organized.

Comment: That's why we can fix other people's questions,

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `fin` from the highest index on, and use it to access elements in lists with this index. that can't be right, as these indices do not exist.

```
b[fin] = a[i]
```

and

```
b[fin] = a[i]
fin += 1
```

and

```
print "La llista és",b[fin]
```

Also in if and else you are append to the list. That doenst make much sense too. You should append once and prepend in the other case

```
def negatius(a):
    fin = len(a) - 1
    i = 0
    b = [i]
    for i in range(fin):
            if a[i] < 0:
                    b = [a[i]] + b  # prepend a to b
            else:
                    b += [a[i]]     # append a to b

    print "La llista és",b

a=[1,-2,3,-4,-3,5,6]
negatius(a)
```

prints

```
La llista és [-3, -4, -2, 0, 1, 3, 5]
```

note that you are adding 0 to the list, i doubt that this is ok.

Comment: The element 0 aren't in my list. The element that have to appears is 6. I try to take out -1 in variable fin but 0 appears in my output i dont want this, how can i take out the 0?

Comment: Why do u add it in the first place?